# Sharepoint authentication without using sharepoint development environment or service references?

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to access a local SharePoint site using a .net program and am having difficulties.

I don't want to use the SharePoint development environment (may have many developers work on this, and that is just one more thing to install).

I would also like to make this configurable so that I can change the site and list name without recompiling.  I don't think I can do that with the Service References.  If I can, how?

I also don't want the user to enter sharepoint validation information, I am ok with storing sharepoint login information in a .config file.

I believe I could do this with REST, but can't figure out how to create an AccessToken without using the Sharepoint development environment.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Honestly, you've chosen the wrong application to mess with. SP is hard enough without trying to bypass the recommended development paths. Even doing REST development with SP is easier with VS and I hate VS. Isn't your SP integrated to the domain? If it is, you can ignore SP for the user stuff, just use Windows authentication. Sorry if that is rubbish, I do SP Online.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I may be close to figuring it out.  I'll post it if I do.

Comment: So you want to have developers dev without a local SharePoint environment?  It is going to be a terrible experience, and they will hate it. You really need a local SharePoint environment in order to develop, deploy and test properly. If your concerned about having on more thing to install, you will have a lot more issues to deal with not having a local SharePoint environment.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I was having was not understanding that you could put other types of credentials in the request.Credentials property.  Here is the code I created:

```
    public bool CopyFileToSharePoint(string fileName, Stream fileStream)
    {
        var data = new byte[fileStream.Length];
        fileStream.Read(data, 0, (int) fileStream.Length);
        fileStream.Close();

        var sharePointPath =
            SharePointWebSiteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('" + SharePointListName + "')" +
            "/RootFolder/Files/add(url='" + fileName + "',overwrite='true')";

        var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(sharePointPath);
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(SharePointUserName, SharePointPassword, SharePointLoginDomain);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Accept = "application/atom+xml";
        request.Headers["X-RequestDigest"] = GetFormDigest(SharePointWebSiteUrl);
        request.ContentType = "application/txt";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;
        request.GetRequestStream().Write(data, 0, data.Length);

        var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
        return response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
    }
```

I'm sure it's not perfect, but it works.